# Sass - Wrapping second version of bootstrap with some styles

Tags: css, sass

Thank you for reading this.

I have 1 element on site, let say looking like this:

```
<div id="other-div"><h1>Test other-div</h1></div>
<div id="app"><h1>Test app</h1></div>
```

I would like div#app, to have only his own styles, which are not applied to the rest of the website. So I tried to do something like this with sass:

```
#app {
    @import "custom.scss";    
}
```

( let say custom css have inside h1 {color:red} )

Problem: 
styles from custom.scss are working also for #other-div. How can I separate these 2 elements? So styles from the rest of the website shouldn't apply to the #app and styles from elements in #app shouldn't apply to the rest if the website

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the official SASS documentation, it says that we can do a nested import. Take a look at this [link](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import)

Alternatively, you can enclose the style in `custom.scss` in a placeholder selector like this:

```
%h1 {
   color: red
}
```

And in your main sass file, include it like this:

```
@import 'custom';   
#app {
     @extend %h1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried nested imports already, problem is that some styles from the import are overriden by main pages style. So i'ts working in some part

Comment: @Bartosz: Try the second(alternative) solution that should work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the custom.scss file.

Add this in the first line

```
#app{
```

and this in the last line of the file.

```
}
```

Then import it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use child selector no need to use sass `#app > h1 { color: red; }` or u can use sass like that `#app { & > h1 { color: red; } }`.